# Can't calculate an eigenvector because the system has no solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find all eigenvalues of the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
2&2&-2\\
2&5&-4\\
-2&-4&5\\
                             \end{pmatrix}$
and find matrix $U$ such that $U^TU=I$ and $U^TAU$ is diagonal.

I calculated and checked that $\lambda_1=10,\lambda_{2,3}=1$. Then eigenvector if $\lambda_1=10$ is  $(1,2,-2)^T$; if $\lambda_{2}=1$ eigenvector is $(0,1,1)^T$. How to find the third eigenvector (if I try to calculate the third eigenvector in this way $(A-I)x=(0,1,1)^T$, the system has no solutions.

Comment: I have not done the calculation, but the relevant question would be what the dimension of the space of solutions of $(A-I)x=0$ is.

Comment: @CarstenS the dimension = 2

Comment: Your eigenvalues for $\lambda_{2,3} = 1$ will be a spanning set for the nullspace of $A-\lambda_{2,3}I$.

Comment: Well then, take an orthonormal basis of that two dimensional space, and you have the two eigenvectors that you need, right? (Btw, I didn't even notice that the matrix is symmetric, my math days seem to be long gone.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a second (linearly independent) *eigenvector* associated with $\lambda = 1$.  That is, you need to find *another* solution $x$ to 
$$
(A - I)x = 0
$$
What you were looking for was a solution to 
$$
(A - I)x = v_1
$$
which would be a *generalized eigenvector*.  Generalized eigenvectors are only useful when the matrix in question fails to be diagonalizable, which is not the case here (since we are meant to diagonalize it).

In fact, in order to have $U^TU = I$, you must select the eigenvectors for $\lambda = 1$ to be both length $1$ and mutually orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

The two eigenvectors you already found are orthogonal. Take their cross product and you'll have the third.

Comment: Your answer is factually correct, but it might be worth mentioning why your scheme works in this example (the original matrix is symmetric, so has an orthogonal eigenbasis by the spectral theorem), lest some casual passerby down the road conclude that a third eigenvector is always generated by crossing two eigenvectors. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  I have a feeling you're going to tell me otherwise but... since the cross product only exists in 3-space, the third eigenvector can in fact always be generated by crossing the other two.

Comment: Crossing eigenvectors works here because the eigenspaces of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal, but for a general (i.e., non-symmetric diagonalizable) matrix that's not the case. For instance, if the OP's matrix had been$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\ 0&2&1\\ 0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$$crossing two eigenvectors would not give a third.